# Reading a file in listBox within columns

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to read a csv file so that it is fetched in form of rows and displayed in a ListBox, But I am unable to arrange in fix columns so that it is in a readable form.

I have tried using multiple columns property but still no luck.

[image: Here what I have done so far]

I expect the output to be like this :

[image: expected output]

**Edit :**

Here is my code for populating listBox

```
foreach (Student person in _result)
            {
                _listResults.Items.Add(person.ToString());
            }
```

Here is the bean class :

```
    class Student
{
    #region FIELDS

    private String _lastName, _firstName;
    private int _exam1, _exam2, _exam3, _finalExam;

    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return _lastName;
        }

        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _firstName;
        }

        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
        }
    }

    public int Exam1
    {
        get
        {
            return _exam1;
        }

        set
        {
            _exam1 = value;
        }
    }

    public int Exam2
    {
        get
        {
            return _exam2;
        }

        set
        {
            _exam2 = value;
        }
    }

    public int Exam3
    {
        get
        {
            return _exam3;
        }

        set
        {
            _exam3 = value;
        }
    }

    public int FinalExam
    {
        get
        {
            return _finalExam;
        }

        set
        {
            _finalExam = value;
        }
    }


    #endregion

    #region CONSTRUCTOR
    public Student()
    {

    }

    public Student(string firstName, string lastName, int exam1, int exam2, int exam3, int final)
    {
        this._firstName = firstName;
        this._lastName = lastName;
        this._exam1 = exam1;
        this._exam2 = exam2;
        this._exam3 = exam3;
        this._finalExam = final;

    }

    #endregion

    #region METHODS

    public void _CalculateAverage(out float average)
    {
        average = _exam1 + _exam2 + _exam3 + _finalExam / 400;

    }

    public void _CalculateLetAverage(out String grade, float average)
    {
        if (average > 85)
            grade = "A+";
        else if (average > 75)
            grade = "A";
        else if (average > 65)
            grade = "B+";
        else if (average > 60)
            grade = "B";
        else if (average > 55)
            grade = "C+";
        else
            grade = "F";

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "   "+_firstName+" "+_lastName 
            + "                              " + _exam1
            + "                  " + _exam2
            + "                  " + _exam3
            + "                " + _finalExam;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: DataGridView and/or ListView are better controls for this task.

Comment: However, if you are willing to change the ListBox font to some Fixed Width font then it is possible to define the columns size in characters units and then prepare a proper text to add to the Items collection. By the way how do you fill the listbox data?

Comment: @Steve i have edited my question, now take a look.

Comment: @Abdullahbinarif As per my answer (and @Steve's suggestion), you can bind your `Student` object directly to a better-suited control to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we have already told you, a **ListBox** is not really the correct control to use when you want your output "aligned" in columns. There is no provision in a ListBox to have a single  line of text formatted in columns. Controls like **ListView** and **DataGridView** are better for this task because they have the concept of columns and you can use them in a natural way.

*However*, if you really want to use a ListBox and have your columns, then you need a compromise. You cannot use fonts with a variable width because in these fonts the letter W and the space have not the same width and this makes a mess to calculate the correct column size (and we are not even starting to talk how to calculate the white space needed to have a correct left/right alignment with different texts).

The compromise requires the use of a [Fixed Width font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) (or Monospace or Fixed Pitch). There are many to choose from. ([Consolas](https://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/Consolas/) is my preferite). After setting the Font property of your listbox to your choosen fixed width font then you need to decide how to size your columns.
In my example below I have decided to have a FirstName column with 20 characters, the LastName with 30 character and the votes column 8 character each.

So your override for the ToString method will be:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{_firstName,-20} {_lastName,-30} " + 
            "{_exam1,8} {_exam2,8} {_exam3,8} {_finalExam,8}";
}
```

Those positive and negative numbers after the variables name are the alignment values as explained in the [Format String Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#format-string-component) (Beware, it is a large topic but worth to read and understand)

Comment: Power to you @steve, can't Believe this is the accepted method of doing it rather than using the right tools for the job - but at the end of the day, if the author's needs are satisified, I guess it's all good lol :D

Comment: Well, that's right. The job should be done with the proper tools and we have warned the OP about that. But I supposed that, at this point in time, an example using a tool already known (the listbox) was a good way to introduce the many options available with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The standard ListBox control is not designed for formatting like this, it's basically just text - and it has no idea how to line up the content of the string with your labels, and nor should it!

Instead, you need a control that is suited to this exact job.  It's called the [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.8).  There are plenty of tutorials online if you search to show you how to work with it.

EDIT: Steve also mentioned [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=netframework-4.8) in his comment, which can also fulfil your needs.